# Java subclass must be in same block its is subclassing?

Tags: java, subclass

By `subclassing` in java, does that mean a subclass must be within the same code block as the class the subclass is subclassing? Or can it be within its own class block?

Example:

```
public void MyClass(){

     private class MySubClass(){

     }
}
```

Compared to:

myClass.java:

```
public void MyClass(){

}
```

mySubclass.java:

```
     private class MySubClass(){

     }
```

Comment: `public void MyClass` is not a class definition, only a method

Comment: I think you are missing some fundamentals of Java programming. I recommend finding some good introductory tutorials and follow those.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of an inner class, which is defined within the scope of a parent class.  A subclass simply extends a parent class:

```
public class Parent { }
public class Child extends Parent { }
```

Comment: Ok. In the context of android programming: if I'd like to create a single class to handle all network requests (in order to avoid redundancy of code). Could I use an AsyncTask (which must be a subclass according to docs.) and call it from anywhere in the codebase?

Comment: I don’t work with Android, so I can’t answer that one precisely, but VERY broadly speaking yes that could be possible with a class.